# Output argument “GC” not assigned during call to “C:\ibm_gc\ammaChirp.m

Tags: matlab

I am calling function GammaChirp in ibm_gc.When I run the code I get the error:???Output argument “GC” (and maybe others) not assigned  during call to “C:\Users\Deepak\Documents\MATLAB\ibm_gc\GCFBv210pack\GammaChirp.m
???Undefined function or method ‘GC’ for input arguments of type ‘double’
Error in =>ibm_gc at 13
The code of ibm_gc.m is as follows:

```
function sig = ibm_gc(target,masker,snr,lc,frs)
% Produce an IBM (ideal binary mask) processed mixture.
% The first variable is required.
% When the second variable is not provided the function returns an all-one
% masked signal.
% snr: input SNR in dB.
% lc: local SNR criterion in dB.
% fRange: frequency range.
% Written by DeLiang Wang at Oticon in Feb'07
target=wavread('C:\Users\Deepak\Documents\MATLAB\17_8_16\clean.wav');
%masker=wavread('C:\Users\Deepak\Documents\MATLAB\17_8_16\babble.wav');
if nargin < 2
    [numChan,numFrame] = size(cochleagram(GammaChirp(target)));
    sig = synthesis(target,ones(numChan,numFrame));  % equivalent to an all-one mask
    return
end 
if nargin < 3
    snr = 0;      % default input SNR is 0 dB
end
if nargin < 4
    lc = 0;       % default lc is 0 dB
end
if nargin < 5
    frs = [80, 5000]; % default frequency range in Hz
end

numChan = 128;      % default is 128 channels
lt = length(target); lm = length(masker);
if (lt >= lm)       % equalize the lengths of the two files
    target = target(1:lm);
else
    masker = masker(1:lt);
end

change = 20*log10(std(target)/std(masker)) - snr;
masker = masker*10^(change/20);     % scale masker to specified input SNR
gt = GammaChirp(target,numChan,frs);
gm = GammaChirp(masker,numChan,frs);

ct = cochleagram(gt);     
cm = cochleagram(gm);

[numChan,numFrame] = size(ct);     % number of channels and time frames

if isinf(-lc)
    mask = ones(numChan,numFrame);  % give an all-one mask with lc = -inf
else
    for c = 1:numChan
        for m = 1:numFrame
            mask(c,m) = ct(c,m) >= cm(c,m)*10^(lc/10);     % this way to avoid division by zero
        end
    end
end    
dlmwrite('mask.out',mask);
mixture = target+masker;
sig = synthesisFast(mixture,mask,frs);
```

The code of GammaChirp.m is as follows:

```
%
%   Gammachirp : Theoretical auditory filter 
%   Toshio IRINO
%   7 Apr. 97 (additional comments)
%   20 Aug. 97 (Simplify & Carrier Selection)
%   10 Jun. 98 (SwNorm)
%   26 Nov. 98 (phase = phase + c ln fr/f0)
%   7  Jan. 2002 (adding 'envelope' option)
%   22  Nov. 2002 (debugging 'peak' option)
%
%   gc(t) = t^(n-1) exp(-2 pi b ERB(Frs)) cos(2*pi*Frs*t + c ln t + phase)
%
%   function [GC, LenGC, Fps, InstFreq ] ...
%          = GammaChirp(Frs,SR,OrderG,CoefERBw,CoefC,Phase,SwCarr,SwNorm);
%   INPUT : Frs : Asymptotic Frequency ( vector )
%       SR  : Sampling Frequency
%       OrderG  : Order of Gamma function t^(OrderG-1)        == n   
%       CoefERBw: Coeficient -> exp(-2*pi*CoefERBw*ERB(f))    == b
%       CoefC   : Coeficient -> exp(j*2*pi*Frs + CoefC*ln(t)) == c
%       Phase   : Start Phase(0 ~ 2*pi)                       
%       SwCarr  : Carrier ('cos','sin','complex','envelope': 3 letters)
%       SwNorm  : Normalization of peak spectrum level ('no', 'peak')
%   OUTPUT: GC  : GammaChirp                     ( matrix )
%       LenGC   : Length of GC for each channel  ( vector )
%               Fps     : Peak Frequency                 ( vector )
%       InstFreq: Instanteneous Frequency        ( matrix )
%
%   
function [GC, LenGC, Fps, InstFreq ] ...
    = GammaChirp(Frs,SR,OrderG,CoefERBw,CoefC,Phase,SwCarr,SwNorm);

if nargin < 2,            help GammaChirp; return; end;
Frs = Frs(:);
NumCh = length(Frs);
if nargin < 3,            OrderG = [];                 end;
if length(OrderG) == 0,   OrderG = 4;                  end; % Default GammaTone
if length(OrderG) == 1,   OrderG = OrderG*ones(NumCh,1); end;
if nargin < 4,            CoefERBw = [];           end; 
if length(CoefERBw) == 0, CoefERBw = 1.019;            end; % Default GammaTone
if length(CoefERBw) == 1, CoefERBw = CoefERBw*ones(NumCh,1); end; 
if nargin < 5,            CoefC  = [];                 end;
if length(CoefC) == 0,    CoefC  = 0;                  end; % Default GammaTone
if length(CoefC) == 1,    CoefC  = CoefC*ones(NumCh,1); end; 
if nargin < 6,            Phase  = [];                  end;
if length(Phase) == 0,    Phase  = 0;                  end; 
if length(Phase) == 1,    Phase  = Phase*ones(NumCh,1); end; 
if nargin < 7,            SwCarr = [];                 end;
if length(SwCarr) == 0,   SwCarr = 'cos';          end;
if nargin < 8,            SwNorm = [];                 end;
if length(SwNorm) == 0,   SwNorm = 'no';           end;


[ERBrate ERBw] = Freq2ERB(Frs);                             % G&M (1990)
LenGC1kHz = (40*max(OrderG)/max(CoefERBw) + 200)*SR/16000;  % 2 Aug 96 
[dummy ERBw1kHz] = Freq2ERB(1000);  

if strcmp(SwCarr,'sin'), Phase = Phase - pi/2*ones(1,NumCh); end;
%%% Phase compensation
Phase = Phase + CoefC.*log(Frs/1000); % relative phase to 1kHz

LenGC = fix(LenGC1kHz*ERBw1kHz./ERBw);

%%%%%  Production of GammaChirp  %%%%%
GC       = zeros(NumCh,max(LenGC));
if nargout > 2, Fps = Fr2Fpeak(OrderG,CoefERBw,CoefC,Frs); end; % Peak Freq.
if nargout > 3, InstFreq = zeros(NumCh,max(LenGC));        end;


for nch = 1:NumCh,
  t = (1:LenGC(nch)-1)/SR;

  GammaEnv = t.^(OrderG(nch)-1).*exp(-2*pi*CoefERBw(nch)*ERBw(nch)*t);
  GammaEnv = [ 0 GammaEnv/max(GammaEnv)];

  if strcmp(SwCarr(1:3),'env') % envelope
    Carrier = ones(size(GammaEnv));
  elseif strcmp(SwCarr(1:3),'com') % complex
    Carrier = [ 0 exp(i * (2*pi*Frs(nch)*t + CoefC(nch)*log(t) +Phase(nch)) )];
  else
    Carrier = [ 0 cos(2*pi*Frs(nch)*t + CoefC(nch)*log(t) +Phase(nch))];
  end;

  GC(nch,1:LenGC(nch)) = GammaEnv.*Carrier;

  if nargout > 3, 
    InstFreq(nch,1:LenGC(nch)) = [0, [Frs(nch) + CoefC(nch)./(2*pi*t)]];
  end;

  if strcmp(SwNorm,'peak') == 1,  % peak gain normalization
     [frsp freq] = freqz(GC(nch,1:LenGC(nch)),1,LenGC(nch),SR);
     fp = Fr2Fpeak(OrderG(nch),CoefERBw(nch),CoefC(nch),Frs(nch));
     [dummy np] = min(abs(freq-fp)); 
     GC(nch,:) = GC(nch,:)/abs(frsp(np));
  end;

end; % nch = ...

return

%% ERBw = 0.128*Frs;     % Complete Constant Q only for check.

% old 
% Amp = ones(NumCh,1);                                  % No normalization
% if strcmp(SwNorm,'peak'),  Amp = ERBw./ERBw1kHz; end; % Peak spectrum==const. 
% when it is gammatone
%  if strcmp(SwNorm,'peak'),   ...
%         Amp = 2.815*sqrt(4/OrderG).*CoefERBw.*ERBw/SR; end;
% Peak spectrum==const. The gain is 1.0 when filtering sinusoid at cf.
% GC(nch,:) = GC(nch,:)/max(abs(freqz(GC(nch,:),1,LenGC(nch))));
%
```

Comment: Define the output.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling GammaChirp with one argument in ibm_gc line 13, since your call is 
GammaChirp(target)

in GammaChirp (just after the signature, about line 32) you have 
if nargin < 2,            help GammaChirp; return; end;

that means: if it is called with 0 or one argument write the help and return: that is you return nothing to the caller, so GC is not assigned and that is why it is complaining.

You should call GammaChirp with more arguments and -anyway- I would throw a more informative exception if at least two arguments are needed (have not gone deeper in the logic of your code, but I guess you need at least two arguments).

Hope this helps